# how to convert Multiple dictionaries to single dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.6

read data from excel sheet using for loop stored key and values in to a dictionaries i get the data below like this in the console window 
{'Name':'Mahesh'}
  {id:345}
that is not my expected result 
now i want convert data like this

{'Name':'Mahesh',id:345}
please can you give me suggestions how can i do this

Answer (score 0):

You can add one dictionary into another using `dict0.update(dict1)`. That adds all the key-value pairs of dict1 into dict0.